# changing .js extension default editor (win7)

Tags: javascript, windows-7, editor, default, file-extension

I used the ShellMenuView utility to find the registry keys associated with the .js extension and changed this key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\JSFile\Shell\Edit\Command
```

from a path to notepad.exe to the notepad++.exe path.

For some reason though the edit context menu still opens with notepad.  I did the same thing for .bat files and it worked fine.  Is there another key that could be overriding it?

Answer (score 2):

A couple possible places. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*` applies to all files regardless of its type. If it has the same `edit` command there will be a conflict (I'm not sure which one takes precedence here).

Also, the route you pointed to are the *global settings*. There is also a per-user file associations located at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`. From there the very same structure follows. Entries from both places are considered to build the context menu, but for those that are duplicated, the per-user settings override the global ones, could be another place to look.